# Editing reputation anomaly can generate unbounded reputation?

Tags: feature-request, editing, reputation, suggested-edits

**Background:**

I was editing an answer given to my question. Edits included some Latex notations. Edit was approved and I got a reputation of $(+2)$. Later, there were some incompleteness in the answer that the OP completed by editing. However, again there were some expressions which were not properly formatted with Latex. I again edited them. However, it was approved and I got another (+2) reputation from editing on the same answer !

**Question:**

Isn't this an anomaly or bug in editing system and should be changed ? For example, it can be used with bad intention by someone secretly to hype their reputation without any bound. A possible solution would be to get a maximum of only $(+2)$ by editing a single post , independent of the number of times it was edited, for a given user. ( Hence, different users will get the reputation of $+2$ by editing a single post but each single user will get it only once ).
Or is it not that a big issue ?

Please note that what I asked in the above question was in general and hypothetical. I am not saying any particular user as a cheater.

Comment: You no longer receive XP for edits after a certain point.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation  Per the Help Center, you can earn a maximum of 1000 reputation from suggesting edits.  Note, also, that once you have earned 2000 reputation, you can edit posts without having them go into the review queue (they no longer need to be approved by other users, and you no longer earn reputation for making edits, whether or not you have hit the 1000 reputation cap for suggested edits).  https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit

Comment: That cannot be done secretly: the reviewers can see it clearly.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Okay. I didn't knew that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am summarizing Xander Henderson's [useful comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35697/editing-reputation-anomaly-can-generate-unbounded-reputation#comment168335_35697):

1. Once you reach 2000 total points, your edits no longer go into the review queue and no longer earn points.
2. Whether you reach 2000 or not, there is a lifetime limit of 1000 points that you can earn from edits.

Source: [Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).